# how can a pointer itself make it NULL?

Tags: c++

```
Obj *obj = new Obj();
obj->destroy();
if (obj == NULL)
    cout << "yes";
```

How to write the method "destroy()" to output "yes"?

Comment: In short: you cannot.

Comment: Don't make things hard on yourself....`void Obj::destroy() { cout << "yes"; }` :)

Comment: ^^ lol, while strictly correct, I suspect that is not what the OP actually wanted:)

Comment: I use a macro for what you appear to be trying to do. `#define destroy(x) {delete x; x = nullptr;}`

Comment: @Logicrat, and what does this macro give you, rather than your share in global warming?

Comment: Don't use a macro when a function would do.  `void destroy(T *& p) { delete p; p = nullptr; }`

Comment: @SergeyA What that macro does for me is that it deletes whatever the pointer points to, *and then sets the pointer to 0*. I find it an expressive and concise way to make sure that the pointer is null after it's been deleted.

Comment: @Logicrat, I can read C++ code quite well. The question is, why it is important for you to have the pointer set to `nullptr` after being deleted? (and a side question - why are you `delete`ing in 2016?)

Comment: @SergeyA There are a number of scenarios in which it may be desirable to delete a pointer and then check it later. The first one that comes to mind has to do with a buffer not being large enough to decompress compressed data, in which case the buffer gets deleted. A zero pointer can then mean either "don't use this buffer" or "we need to reallocate". (side answer - my company has a lot of seriously old legacy code that I often have to update)

Comment: @Logicrat, but how do you know there are no copies of the same pointer lying around?

Comment: @SergeyA Careful analysis of the relevant source code. It's not unusual for me to see locally declared pointers whose entire existence is contained within a few dozen lines of code, yet are allocated and possibly deleted within that range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible, because `obj` is a **local variable**. `destroy()` does not have access to any local variables at the call site.

What you are asking is as impossible as this:

```
void f()
{
    // set main's i to some other value? --> impossible
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    f();
    if (i == 1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As for your example, the `this` pointer which can be accessed within `destroy()` does point to the dynamically allocated `Obj` object, but how is supposed to know about any other pointers to that same `Obj` object? It cannot. That's how the language works.

Technically, of course, you can just pass a reference to the local variable:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Obj
{
    void destroy(Obj*& ptr)
    {
        ptr = nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Obj *obj = new Obj();
    obj->destroy(obj);
    if (obj == nullptr)
        std::cout << "yes";
}
```

Practically, however, this does not make any sense at all and is not idiomatic in C++. There is some underlying problem you try to solve. You probably want to make sure that `destroy()` is not called on null pointers, or that pointers to destroyed objects are no longer used. That goal is correct, but your strategy is wrong. Have a look at [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for a completely different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The object controls itself, but it does not control the pointers pointing at it. It is not even aware of the pointers pointing at it (there might be many).

You could take the opposite approach though by using a unique_ptr or shared_ptr, like this:

- Instead of having "teardown" logic in `destroy()`, put it in the destructor of `Object`.
- Use a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a standard pointer.

Then you end up with something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Obj> ptr(new Obj());
// ... do things with ptr ...
ptr.reset(nullptr);  // Does teardown automatically and sets ptr to null
```